# Cursor cannot find a column when foreign key is setup

Tags: android, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, cursor

I have been trying this for long now. I am trying to retrieve contents from the database based on Ids. Every thing worked fine until I introduced INNER JOIN and the WHERE clause to my statement. I got this error

**ERROR**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: classes_sections.classes_sections_ids (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM classes INNER JOIN classes_sections ON classes_sections.classes_sections_ids = classes.classes_sections_id WHERE classes.classes_id =2
```

I think the problem is from my foreign key references and my query too. I really need your help here.I am stuck at this point. Thank you.

This is Where I declared my constants used in the database (FK means Foreign Key and PK primary key)

```
//Classes Table Columns names
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_ID = "classes_id";
private static final String COLUMN_CLASS_ITEM_INDEX ="class_item_index";
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME = "classes_name";
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_CODENAME = "classes_codename";
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS = "classes_sections_id";//FK
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_TEACHERS = "classes_teachers";//FK
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_STUDENTS = "classes_students";//FK

//Classes Sections Table Column names
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID = "classes_sections_ids";//PK
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME = "classes_sections_name";
private static final String COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_DESCRIPTION = "classes_sections_description";
```

Here is The code for my tables

```
 // create classes_table sql query
private String CREATE_CLASSES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLASSES + "("
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_CLASS_ITEM_INDEX + " NUMBER,"
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_CODENAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_CLASSES_TEACHERS
        + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_STUDENTS + " VARCHAR,"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " INTEGER) REFERENCES " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS  + "(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE  " + ");";



//create sections sql query
private String CREATE_CLASSES_SECTIONS_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + "("
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME + " VARCHAR,"
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR" + ")";
```

This Method retrieves data from database by ID

```
public ArrayList<SectionsBean> getAllSectionsByClassesID(long id){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "
            + "classes INNER JOIN classes_sections ON classes_sections.classes_sections_ids = classes.classes_sections_id WHERE classes.classes_id =" + id;

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    ArrayList<SectionsBean> sectionsBeanList = new ArrayList<SectionsBean>();

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);


    Log.i("Query details", String.valueOf(cursor));
    Log.d("DataDetails", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


        ClassesBean classesBean = new ClassesBean();
        classesBean.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_ID)));
        classesBean.setClasses_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME)));


        SectionsBean sectionsBean = new SectionsBean();
        sectionsBean.setSectionsID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID)));
        sectionsBean.setSections_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME)));



        sectionsBean.setClassesBean(classesBean);
        sectionsBeanList.add(sectionsBean);

    }
    return sectionsBeanList;

}
```

Comment: Hi If you would output your SQL code strings, you/we could try them in an SQL environment. Eg sqlfiddle.com. And where is your DDL? How can we see whether you defined that column that is said to not exist? Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is possibly due to a typing error, perhaps that  `classes_sections` does not equate to whatever `TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS` resolves to.

I'd suggest that you ALWAYS only use a single source for all database components (database tables columns).

Thus instead of :-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "
            + "classes INNER JOIN classes_sections ON classes_sections.classes_sections_ids = classes.classes_sections_id WHERE classes.classes_id =" + id;
```

you should build the query along the lines of :-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +
    TABLE_CLASSES +
    " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
    " ON " +
    TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID +
    " = " + TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
    " WHERE " + 
    TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS +
    " = " + String.valueOf(id);
```

#### Note

- this is in-principle code, it has not been tested, so may contain typing errors.

### EDIT

On closer inspection there is also an issue with the definition of the **classes** table in that you have effectively coded :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (
        classes_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        class_item_index NUMBER,
        classes_name" VARCHAR,
        classes_codename VARCHAR, 
        classes_sections_id INTEGER,
        classes_teachers VARCHAR,
        classes_students VARCHAR,
        FOREIGN KEY(classes_sections_id INTEGER) REFERENCES classes_sections  (classes_sections_ids)  ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

The table constraint definition is syntactically incorrect as the column_name parameter accepts a list of 1 or more comma separated column names. **INTEGER** is not a valid keyword according to :-

[image]

[CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

As such you should change :-

```
// create classes_table sql query
private String CREATE_CLASSES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLASSES + "("
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_CLASS_ITEM_INDEX + " NUMBER,"
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_CODENAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_CLASSES_TEACHERS
        + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_STUDENTS + " VARCHAR,"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " INTEGER) REFERENCES " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS  + "(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE  " + ");";
```

to (*i.e. remove **INTEGER** from the column_names parameter**) :-

```
 // create classes_table sql query
private String CREATE_CLASSES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLASSES + "("
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_CLASS_ITEM_INDEX + " NUMBER,"
        + COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_CODENAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_CLASSES_TEACHERS
        + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_CLASSES_STUDENTS + " VARCHAR,"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS  + "(" + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE  " + ");";
```

#### Note

- This change will require that the classes table be dropped and recreated.

  - The simplest way to afford this, but with the cost of losing all data, is to delete the database in which case the `onCreate` method (assuming you are using a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper aka a DatabaseHelper) will be invoked.
  - You can either clear/delete the App's data or uninstall the App which will effectively delete the database.

#### Additional

Using the following SQL which was derived from the above works (syntactically) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS classes;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (
        classes_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        class_item_index NUMBER,
        classes_name VARCHAR,
        classes_codename VARCHAR, 
        classes_sections_id INTEGER,
        classes_teachers VARCHAR,
        classes_students VARCHAR,
        FOREIGN KEY(classes_sections_id) REFERENCES classes_sections  (classes_sections_ids)  ON DELETE CASCADE);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS classes_sections;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes_sections (
        classes_sections_ids INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        classes_sections_name VARCHAR,
        classes_sections_description VARCHAR);
SELECT * FROM classes INNER JOIN classes_sections ON classes_sections.classes_sections_ids = classes.classes_sections_id WHERE classes.classes_id =2
```

i.e. :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MikeT I have seen your answer , I will try it latter today

Comment: ok @MikeT I have tried your code and the suggested edit, The Error has gone but this time the code does not retrieve anything. What could be the issue at this point.

Comment: This is what shows up in the logcat as contents of the cursor. `D/DataDetails: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@24ff741
                                                                               <<<<<` meaning no data is present in the cursor  @MikeT

Comment: The tables are empty, the classes table has rows but no referenced classes_sections row, there are no classes rows that match the selection criteria.

Comment: But how is that possible. @MikeT I add sections first in the app using a small add button before I click on classes to retrieve all data. What could be the issue.?

Comment: The classes Id are gotten as a result of the position (getItemId) from the recyclerview. @MikeT

Comment: Faced with such an issue. I copy the database file to my pc, load it into an SQLite (I use SQLite Manager a Firefox extension) tool and then check/develop the query (e.g. the above screen shot is from SQLite Manager). Perhaps you are under the misconception that coding foreign key magically creates references, whilst using foreign key purely adds a rule that must be met, so perhaps there are no references from classes to class_sections.

Comment: I'd suggest that you mark this question as answered and then ask a new question. Along the lines of why doesn't this query select any rows. Including the query and the data held by the relevant tables.

Comment: I should get SQLite and run the query as well. @MikeT. Where can I download it?

Comment: Here's a link to [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: "I copy the database file to my pc" as you said. Wherer can I find this file? @MikeT

Comment: You should have had a dialog asking you where to save it (note you might have to select All Files to see it as it may/may not have an extension i.e. if you call the database mydb, it won;t have an extension if you call it mydb.sqlite then it will have sqlite extension i.e. the db name exactly matches the file name).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166274/discussion-between-miket-and-aham-uzoma).